# How can I fill a field in Django with the username?

Tags: python, django

I have a model, `configuration`, in Django and wish to fill the `author` field with `get_username` 
Can this be done within the model or must it be done from the form? If it must be on the form, how can I change the standard admin page to have this functionality? 
At present, the model reads thus:

```
class Configuration(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=False)
author = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)

created = models.DateTimeField("date created",auto_now_add=True)
modified = models.DateTimeField("date modified",auto_now=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=512)
drawing =  models.ForeignKey(Drawing)
instruments = models.ManyToManyField(Instrument)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `models.ForeignKey`:

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Configuration(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

#admin.py:
class Configuration_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'author',....)
```

Comment: All of these solutions result in `Database Error. no such column: <App-Name>_configuration.author_id`

Comment: @RowanIngram You need to drop the table first and sync it again. Or better use [south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ...
    ...
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some relationship between your model and default User model then you can extends the User model into your own custom model , like this:

*models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Configuration(models.Model):
   author = models.OneToOneField(User)
   ..
   ..
```